# Requirements for properties being resolved with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-keyvault

I am using Azure KeyVault in Spring Boot to resolve secrets. The vault has a limitation in that properties can only be separated by `-`. I am using `azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter` and this dependency replaces dashes with dots to be able to store secrets such as `spring-datasource-url`.

In my project we are using a fairly complex KeyVault and this requires us to prefix properties to know who owns them. So I store my property as `prefix-sampleProperty` in the vault. The vault starter lets my use this property on two different ways:

```
@Value("${prefix.sampleProperty}"
@Value("${prefix-sampleProperty}"
```

However, since my part of the application is only interested in a single namespace within this vault (the `prefix` namespace), I want to use the Spring annotation `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")` and simply disregard writing it for each property:

```
@Value("${sampleProperty}"
```

However, this does not work and fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'sampleProperty' in value "${sampleProperty}"
```

I have verified that my environment variables in Spring contain the property, and it exists in two forms, both with `.` (dot) and `-` (dash). They exist under `propertySource -> source -> propertySources -> propertySourcesList -> KeyVaultPropertySource` when Spring attempts to resolve the value from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java#L85).

All available property sources that Spring iterates through:
[image]

When Spring calls `propertySource.getProperty(key);`, key is `sampleProperty`, which does not exist, only `prefix-sampleProperty` and `prefix.sampleProperty` do.

This in turn calls [this method](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/2.1.2/azure-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/spring/KeyVaultOperation.java#L56), and here `secretName` is also `sampleProperty`, which does not exist in the map in this class.

So, my questions:

Are there any specific requirements for resolving properties with class level annotation `ConfigurationProperties` other than it has to be separated by `.`?

Are there any specific requirements for how to add properties to Springs environment to be able to resolve them with `ConfigurationProperties`?

Is this a fault in the implementation of the Azure KeyVault property source?

**Edit:**

```
@Getter
@Component
// @EnableConfigurationProperties // also tried here, not working
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
public class SampleConfiguration {

    private String sampleProperty;

}
```

I also added `@EnableConfigurationProperties` at the same place where I added `@SpringBootApplication`. This is how I wire the configuration:

```
@Configuration
// @EnableConfigurationProperties(DataLakeConfiguration.class) // also tried, no difference. also removed autowired
public class AzureBeanConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public AzureBeanConfiguration(final SampleConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ADLStoreClient getDataLakeClient() {
        // All properties on configuration object is null here
    }
}
```

If I instead use this, it works:

```
@Getter
@Configuration
public class SampleConfiguration {

    @Value("${prefix.sampleProperty}") // or prefix-sampleProperty
    private String sampleProperty;

}
```

**Edit 2:**

Config class is annotated with:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
public class SampleConfiguration {
    private String sampleProperty;
}
```

I set a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/2.1.6/azure-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/spring/KeyVaultPropertySource.java#L27), and when I hit it the parameter `name` equals `prefix`. I never receive anything like `prefix.sampleProperty` or anything containing that key, nothing resembling the name `sampleProperty`.

Comment: Binding is automatically done when using `@ConfigurationProperties` don;'t mix with `@Value`.

Comment: @M.Deinum not even if I want a different name for the property?

Comment: No. Then you would have to do the binding yourself using the `Binder` abstraction in Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried it but I don't get the properties to resolve at all now. The application launches but the properties are null. It seems like the get method in `KeyVaultOperation` isn't even called.

Comment: You have to either annotate the `@ConfigurationProperties` with `@Component` or specify it in `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: I already had `@Configuration` annotation. I tried with `@Component` also but no luck.

Comment: It has to be a component and not created with `new`. Next to that you will need to add `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to enable the support.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think I've done what you said but I cant get it to work. I don't know what I'm missing... It works fine as soon as the properties come from a `properties` file. I've added my usage above.

Comment: You should also have setter methods... Judging from the annotations you are only generating the getters.

Comment: I think I found the root of the problem. When I add the annotation the `getProperty` method of `KeyVaultPropertySource` receives only the prefix, and there is no property matching only the prefix. The method receives `prefix`, and  then looks for a key with that name but there is none, only `prefix.sampleProperty`.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with that. It doesn't matter which propertysource is consulted. When you have properly added the setters (which is required for `@ConfigurationProperties` to work!). It will use the `prefix` + `property` to obtain the value. If you don't have a setter and try to abuse `@Value` then it simply won't work.

Comment: I updated my post to hopefully shed some light on what I mean. I've been using this annotation before and its been straight-forward when fetching from `application.properties`.

Comment: Remove `@Configuration` and use the `EnableConfigurationProperties` on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. If you dont get the prefix applied there must be something else going on, which might be related to the fact it is annotated with `@Configuration` instead of `@Component` the first is treated differently.

Comment: Still no luck, I've tried with so many permutations of `Configuration`, `Component`, `EnableConfigurationProperties`, `ConfigurationProperties` that it's starting to become dizzying. No matter what, the place where I access the properties always contains null for the property values, and the implemented method `getProperty` in `org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource` only receives the prefix declared in the `ConfigurationProperties`annotation, never any field names from the class annotated.

Comment: There must be something in your configuration/setup breaking things. I have been using `@ConfigurationProperties` on a series of projects without issues. Either with `@ConfigurationProperties` /`@EnableConfigurationProperties` or with `@ConfigurationProperties`/`@Component`. Either way it worked.

Comment: Yeah, same here. I use it extensively throughout the rest of the application, it just doesn't seem to work when using it conjunction with the Azure dependency. Thank you for your help, I will try to resolve this.

Comment: Could be that that is initialized very very early in the process not having initialized everything fully. Or maybe you are using an incompatible version leading to different versions of libraries being pulled in.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it is initialized very early using the `Ordered` interface. I think it is close to `Integer.MIN`.

Comment: I created a completely clean project with only the key vault dependency and it works, the issue is with my setup. I'm using a multi module maven project so that might be an issue.